# How to implement RPL routing in NS2/NS3

Tags: ns2

I want to develop RPL routing protocol in NS2 but unable to work it in RPL specially in NS2.
any one can suggest me is there any patch file or examples for RPL routing available or not please suggest me your suggestion is really important for me.

Comment: I think there a ns2 implemenataion for that if you want contact send me commanet I will send you an email

Comment: Alex I need your help regarding RPL implementation in NS2/ Ns3, Would you provide me your mail id so i can contact you about same or please contact me on my mail id kingid2006@gmail.com.